# Why span width gets ignored?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I found such a situation in my code and can't find an explanation for it. Why does Chrome (and other browsers as well) set width to auto, ignoring my `width: 15px`?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Inline elements don't have a width.

Comment: Please post both classes in your question. And add the line numbers with them aswell if you can.

Comment: firebug is more capable with css3. sometimes chrome doesn't give the right debug info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`span`s are `inline` elements. You can't set the width of an `inline` element.

In order to set the width you've to change the `display` property of the element.

```
.elem {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I suggest these reading to learn more about CSS box model:

- [The CSS box model](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)
- [Understanding inline box model/](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/)